# How do I create a fields_for a potentially unlimited number of children objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, activerecord, model

I'm making an application that involves booking appointments for users. I have a User model and an AvailableDate model. The user has_many availble_dates and the AvailableDate belongs_to user.

I want to present a form for the user so that they can mark a couple of dates in a calendar and each of the dates they mark will become an AvailableDate object tied to that user.

At the moment my solution is to do all the work that a form_for helper would normally do manually. This involves a lot of javascript and is generally just getting far too messy.

I can't figure out how I should make a form_for tag work when I need to create potentially infinitely many dates. In theory a user could keep marking off dates in the future as available. If I knew how many dates I needed to create for a user, I could do user.available_dates.build, N times. But this doesn't work here.

Can anyone help? It like this problem should be pretty common. Am I designing my application wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to render the fields for your association once, outside the form.

When the user performs whatever interaction that should create a new set of inputs you use javascript to clone the initial set of fields and insert them into the form. The one thing you need to do is change the name of these inputs so that they are unique. Usually people use the current time in milliseconds for this unique identifier.

Comment: That is almost exactly what my current solution is and I am trying to get away from. Sure its possible, but it gets so messy that I am sure there has to be a better way to do it in rails

Answer (score 0):

Been there & have found several resources to help: [Tutorial](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/) & [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

The bottom line is you need to ensure [child_index](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for#512-Setting-child-index-while-using-nested-attributes-mass-assignment) is unique for each field. The tutorial I use has `child_index: Time.now.to_i` to create a truly unique id, consequently allowing you to add as many fields as you want

The best way to do this:

> - Render `fields_for` as a partial (passing your form builder object)
> - When you want to add new field, create `ajax_field` action
> - Make `ajax_field` view have its own `form_builder`
> - Both your original & `ajax_field` forms will call the partial
> - On front-end, you can use JS to `GET` new form action & append field to page

I can give you code if you want